# 1000 locker java problem without using array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have written a program for a class homework about the 1000 locker problem without the use of array but I'm not getting the required output.

This is the locker problem:

A high school has 1000 students and 1000 lockers, one locker for each student. On the first day of school, the principal plays the following game:

She asks the first student to open all the lockers. She then asks the second student to close all the even-numbered lockers. The third student is asked to check every third locker. If it is open, the student closes it; if it is closed, the student opens it. The fourth student is asked to check every fourth locker. If it is open, the student closes it; if it is closed, the student opens it. The remaining students continue this game.

In general, the nth student checks every nth locker. If it is open, the student closes it; if it is closed, the student opens it. After all the students have taken turns, some of the lockers are open and some are closed.

It requires me to prompt the user to enter the number of lockers and to output the number of lockers and the locker numbers that are open. While researching it, I believe that the output should be a list of perfect square numbers if I`m correct.

This is the code that I have written so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int studentVisitCount = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter the number of lockers: ");
    int numberOfLockers = keyboard.nextInt();
    for (int x = 1; x <= numberOfLockers; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
            if (x % y == 0) {

                studentVisitCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of lockers and students are: " + numberOfLockers);
    if (studentVisitCount % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(studentVisitCount + " ");
        System.out.println("The locker numbers of lockers that are left open at the end of the game are: ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code; it is impossible to read as is, and most edtors these days can reformat at the touch of a button.

Comment: During your research, shouldn't you also find the formula for calculating the number of perfect squares in a range, and how to check if a number is a perfect square?

Comment: If the result is all of the square numbers up to a threshold then why not use that fact more directly in your program?

Comment: But what is your question?

Answer (score -1):

You're right, the open doors would be the perfect square door numbers, because the perfect square number i would be visited 3 times (by 1, sqrt(i), i, apart from 1 which would be visited once), changing the door state as Closed->Open->Closed->Open. The number of perfect squares <= numberOfLockers are i*i for each i from 1...square-root(numberOfLockers), so you can do something like this using/without using an array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of lockers: ");
        int numberOfLockers = keyboard.nextInt();

        // With array
        boolean[] isDoorOpen = new boolean[numberOfLockers + 1];

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfLockers; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= numberOfLockers; j += i) {
                isDoorOpen[j] = !isDoorOpen[j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfLockers; i++) {
            if (isDoorOpen[i])
                System.out.println(i);
        }

        // Without array
        System.out.printf("The number of lockers and students are: %s%n", numberOfLockers);
        System.out.println("The locker numbers of lockers that are left open at the end of the game are: ");

        for(int i=1; i<=Math.sqrt(numberOfLockers); i++) {
            System.out.println(i*i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If we see the pattern, we realize that total numbers of open/close operations that will happen in a particular locker is equals to its total number of divisors. Therefore, if a number have odd number of divisors then its final state will be open, otherwise it will be close.

Now in order to find the number of divisors of a particular number, we can represent number as `n = p^q` then, total divisors will be `(q + 1)`, divisors being `1, p, p^2, ...., p^q` [similarly if `n = p^q * r^s`, we can find number of divisors as `(q + 1) * (s + 1)`]. Therefore, in order to `(q + 1)` to be odd, `q` must be even number. Hence, if a number can be represented as perfect square ( like `p^2`) then it will have odd number of divisors.

Now if we want to just find number of lockers that will be open in the end out of `n` lockers, we can find it in `O(logn)` time complexity by simply calculating integer representation of square root of `n`.

```
int numberOfLockersThatWillBeOpen = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
```

But in order to print all the locker numbers that are open as well as find numbers of lockers that will be open, we can just iterate over all the numbers from 1 to n, and check whether their square is smaller than or equal to `n` and break loop as soon as we notice square is greater than `n`.

```
int numberOfLockersThatWillBeOpen = 0;
List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int x = 1; x <= numberOfLockers; x++) {
      if ((x * x) <= numberOfLockers) {
         numberOfLockersThatWillBeOpen++;
         ans.add(x);// put x into list to print it later 
      } else {
         break;
      }
}
```

Since we are iterating upto square root of `n`, therefore time complexity of above solution will be `O(sqrt(n))`.